# Jetpack Copmose, center text in TextField

Tags: android, uitextfield, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

Is it possible to center text in TextField?

`textStyle = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center)` seems not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {text = it},
    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
)
```

[image]